# Is it possible to make a displace modifier collide with other objects? if not, is there a way to make the food not go through the cooking pot?

Tags: animation, physics, displacement, vertex-groups, collision

I want to make the animation of the displacement to collide with the cooking pot, I already set the two objects with rigid body physics but it just goes through[image]

Answer (score 0):

See Vertex Groups.  There are plenty of postings here at BSE to be searched.

By selecting the top of the delicious tuna fish casserole in *Edit Mode* and making it into  a vertex group named say "TCTOP" you can displace only exactly the top of mesh.

Answer (score 0):

No, modifiers themselves cannot collide. You need to apply them first and **then** apply collision to the modified object.

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure? I remember using a subdivision modifier for cloth simulation... It was some time ago, I might be wrong :)

Comment: @Jachym Michal: I used subdivision with cloth recently. Cloth sim, though,  **requires** subdivision to work so it's possible.